# Creating a DB in RAM on a BlackBerry device. Possible?

Tags: database, memory, blackberry, ram

My app reads a feed from a server on the app start. it then inserts all the data into a SQLite DB and the data is only read during the a instance of the running app, the data is current.

Unfortunately SQLite wont run on Blackberry devices without a SDCard and not all device have a device storage option.

Is there any way to create a DB during app-load in RAM and then close on unload?
I've looked at DB's that do this in Java like H2 but what about getting something like that to work on a BB device?

Answer (score 1):

well how big is your app? do you really need a db or just a few tables to hold data while the app is running? couldnt you just implement a small mini super simple db?

Comment: Hi Memo. The Max amount of records to be inserted will be about 200. The app isn't complex and is about 700K. What do you suggest referring to a a "small mini super simple db"?

Comment: well i was just thinking that if you only have one table with only 200 records, you can just use a hashmap and have all your records in memory like that, i dont see why you need a database in this case.